# Why does an svg with viewbox of different ratio to dimensions renders element in center?

Tags: svg, viewbox

I am trying to understand why in the following svg the element appears in the center

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="400" height="100"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     style="outline: 1px solid green"
>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="75" height="100" fill="#2222FF"  stroke="green"/>
</svg>
```

My understanding is that `viewBox` would take the box defined by the coordinates `0,0 - 100,100` on the svg and map it to the 400x100 image. So that *should* give me a top-to-bottom rectangle that reaches 3/4 of the way across. At the very least I would expect the rectangle to be all the way on the left.

I cannot for the life of me understand why the rectangle here appears in the center. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the default [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) is `xMidYMid`.

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed lead me to the right answer. I'll mark it correct since there are no others but ideally you could build it out more so its more useful to anyone who came along later.